# Change the view of the array

Tags: google-bigquery

How can i change the view of the array for this query`select ['apple', 'orange', 'cucumber'] as name, 'Alice' student`  ? I want to see instead of this view

[image]

that view

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below:

```sql
SELECT FORMAT('%T', ['apple', 'orange', 'cucumber']) AS name;
-- or
SELECT TO_JSON_STRING(['apple', 'orange', 'cucumber']) AS name;
```

[image]